# Why both condition are checked in logical AND operation in csh if first condition return false

Tags: scripting, csh

```
#!/bin/csh
set i=0
if ($i == 1 && { -e $HOME_EXIST } )then
  echo "Hi"
else
  echo "Hello"
endif
```

Why both condition are checked in logical AND operation in csh if first condition return false ?

I am getting following error :

> HOME_EXIST: Undefined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$?` to check if the var is defined:
`if ($?HOME_EXIST) then
    (do whatever you want)
endif`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that even though && is lazy, csh will try to substitute $HOME_EXIST before it starts to evaluate the expression: [Reference](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#C_Shell).
You could get around this problem by using nested ifs.

```
#!/bin/csh
set i=0
if ($i == 1)then
    if(-e $HOME_EXIST)then
        echo "Hi"
    endif
else
    echo "Hello"
endif
```

Comment: I don't want to use nested ifs. If is use nested ifs then i have to use repeated code.

Comment: @UndefinedBehaviour If you want nice looking code then don't use csh :-)

Comment: This code would need an additional `else` for the inner `if` or some other way to print `Hello` when the 1st condition is true and the 2nd condition false.